# Command to find information about CPUs on a UNIX machine

Tags: unix, cpu

Do you know if there is a UNIX command that will tell me what the CPU configuration for my Sun OS UNIX machine is? I am also trying to determine the memory configuration. Is there a UNIX command that will tell me that?

Answer (score 53):

There is no standard Unix command, AFAIK. I haven't used Sun OS, but on Linux, you can use this:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Sorry that it is Linux, not Sun OS. There is probably something similar though for Sun OS.

Comment: Yeah, I said I don't use Sun OS, so I wouldn't know. Anyway, that is not standard Unix.

Answer (score 14):

The nproc command shows the number of processing units available:
$ nproc
Sample outputs: 4

lscpu gathers CPU architecture information form /proc/cpuinfon in human-read-able format:
$ lscpu
Sample outputs:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
CPU socket(s):         2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1866.669
BogoMIPS:              3732.83
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7

Comment: Not on Solaris; even if you build your own `lscpu` you get ` /proc/sys/kernel/hostname: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 13):

Try [psrinfo](http://www.sunsolarisadmin.com/general/psrinfo-find-number-of-physical-virtual-processors-in-solaris-10/) to find the processor type and the number of physical processors installed on the system.

Comment: More specifically, psrinfo  -v | less

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it probably depends which version of Solaris you're running, but also what hardware you have.

On SPARC at least, you have `psrinfo` to show you processor information, which run on its own will show you the number of `CPU`s the machine sees. `psrinfo -p` shows you the number of physical processors installed. From that you can deduce the number of threads/cores per physical processors.

`prtdiag` will display a fair bit of info about the hardware in your machine. It looks like on a V240 you do get memory channel info from `prtdiag`, but you don't on a T2000. I guess that's an architecture issue between UltraSPARC IIIi and UltraSPARC T1.

Comment: psrinfo works with Solaris on x86 too. prtdiag used to be SPARC only but is no more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use prtdiag or prtconf on many UNIXs

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is to look at the boot messages.  If it's been recently booted try running /etc/dmesg.  Otherwise find the boot messages, logged in /var/adm or some place in /var.